# debian init.d script not running after reboot

Tags: linux, debian, init.d

I need to start my Wildfly AS through .sh script after system boot (Linux-Debian). So I created my own script which should do it in init.d:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/starter

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting"
    nohup /home/xxx/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh &
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping"
    /home/xxx/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/starter {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

This **works** if i use it on my own: `/etc/init.d/starter start`.

Then I used command to create symlinks: `update-rc.d starter defaults`. Symlinks are created just as expected, however after `reboot` command the script is not executed.

Does someone knows what prevents my script from being executed after boot? Thank you for all your advices.

Comment: Which version of Debian?  Debian v6 or later replaced *update-rc.d* with *inserve*... see Debian Wiki [How to add a service when using dependency-based booting] (https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot)

Comment: @agc Thank you for your reply. Im runing 8.3. In man insserv i read: "It is not recommended to execute insserv directly unless you know exactly what you're doing, doing so may render your boot system inoperable. update-rc.d is the recommended interface for managing init scripts." So that is not the problem.

Comment: Sorry -- I missed that.  Hmm, permissions, maybe.  Is there anything unusual in the output of this:  **find /etc/rc?.d/ -name '*starter' -exec ls -l '{}' \; ; ls -l /etc/init.d/starter**   Typically every link should be owned by *root* and be file mode 'lrwxrwxrwx (0777)', the file itself has mode '-rwxrwxr-x (0775)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that i did not know that **initial script must set its own $PATH and other variables**. I found it out when I saw java:not found in /var/log/daemon. At the end I found that wildfly has its own scirpt **init-debian.sh**. I used it and it works.